# Logging events once cmd is launched

Tags: command, virus

not a high end coder by any means but can copy and paste and troubleshoot.

I have a situation similar to that described here:
http://www.troublefixers.com/computer-shutdown-restart-when-you-type-cmd-in-run-to-launch-command-prompt/

so running command line, my PC shuts down
Following the above instructions I could not locate any of the 4 or 5 files known to cause this behaviour. So my question is:

Is there a way to record a log file of what happens, as soon as I type cmd?
So if I trigger the unwanted shutdown, is there a way I can store the sequence of events so I can see in a text document (after restarting) where the bad code is being run from?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: have you try to show hidden files? maybe they're hidden.

Comment: what version of windows are you using?

Comment: Hi Polar, Win 8.1 and hidden files are shown.. I assume this virus has new names for its components now. That link in my first post is quite old.

unless typing cmd+enter shuts down my computer for some other reason.

Comment: have you try navigating into `windows\system32` directory and from there open cmd?

Comment: your second option could be running `Powershell` instead of `Command Prompt ` and execute your script on it. You may want to search for Powershell script to convert your cmd script on it.

Comment: Another option is to start `Safe mode ` and then try to start cmd from their, or you can troubleshoot from their too. just make sure to start windows in safe mood with specific running application so the virus won't start in safe mood.

Comment: here to start safe mood => http://www.digitalcitizen.life/5-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-8-windows-81

Comment: Im actually trying to run cmd for unrelated reasons. There's no actual solution there if I can get the console to stay open. If I can get it to stay open the bug is killed or at least thwarted. So Powershell doesn't really offer me anything that I can see as help. Hence wanting to try and log each thing that happens, and ideally use that info to run a search and find the offender that way. I will try launching from the system32 folder and see.

Comment: I tried launching cmd.exe from powershell and nothing seemed to happen including no consequential shutdown.. I might not be calling it right but powershell didn't give any feedback reflecting that either. Cheers

Comment: Actually launching it from the System32 folder doesn't cause my computer to shut down...Does that help isolate things at all?

Comment: Start your windows in safe mood and try to do the instructions from the link you given, if the link above doe's not work then this mean you have a different virus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if it's not protocol to answer my own question and sorry for taking your time Polar, but it turns out this is user error.

My original task was making Windows 8.1 recognise a 3TB hard drive as it was sure it was a 2TB one. Its a MBR versus a GPT thing. An early step was to reinstall the bios according to the techs at acer and that may have created a $acer$.cmd file. My technique is to press windows key and type cmd enter and this was highlighting this $acer$.cmd file not actually cmd.exe. The first time I opened this file in notepad it appeared to be blank, and I ruled this out as the problem but when my partner was helping troubleshoot she did the same thing and found shutdown code in there. Apparently that file was made in 2007 but the computer wouldn't have existed then and my only guess was it appeared as part of the bios reset. I renamed it as .txt file and it's now not whats launched.

In any case it's resolved and I feel a bit foolish but appreciate you offering advice. Hope I can return the favor one day!

Comment: will do as a new user I have to wait 24 hours